# Getting shifted movement and editing keys to work on the console

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, console

In most text editors I use (Emacs, Nano, etc.), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> allow me to skip forwards and backwards in the document one word at a time.  Similarly, I can typically use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to select text to the left and right one character at a time, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to select a word at a time, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to select a page at time, and so on.  These movement and selection key combinations work regardless whether the editor is run as a native X11 application or in text mode in an X11 terminal emulator (e.g., running Emacs with `emacs -nw` in a Konsole or GNOME Terminal window).

However, when I switch to a *real* text-mode console (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or by stopping my X server) and run the editors from there, I find these movement and selection key combinations no longer work.  For example, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> behave exactly the same as a bare <kbd>Left</kbd>.  I don't think this is a problem with the editors themselves, because when I use bash to read these three keys (or key combinations) from the console, they all result in the same escape codes:

```
$ read
^[[C
$ read
^[[C
$ read
^[[C
```

The standard cut/copy/paste key combinations (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>) seem to have the same problem.

Is it possible to configure my text console so that using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifiers on the usual movement and editing keys send the usual codes expected by editors like Nano and Emacs?  All these key combinations worked fine in text mode back in the days of MS-DOS, so I'm a bit surprised that they don't work by default on my GNU/Linux machine.  (If it makes any difference, I'm using openSUSE 13.2.)

Comment: when you say *real text-mode console* do you mean a command prompt in a terminal? The line editing features on a command line are part of the shell that is handling your command. you would use the `bind` command to get the behaviour you want

Comment: No, I mean editing text in an editor like Emacs, not editing a command line in a shell like bash.

Comment: It's possible to modify the keymaps for the Linux *virtual consoles*, but the only examples which have been presented on this forum are trivial cases, showing how 1-2 keys can be setup.

Comment: oh right, you mean when you run emac in a linux terminal? good question... maybe emacs is behaving differently because its detecting a different `$TERM`

Comment: Is there no existing mapping I could use that will make all the keys send the same codes they usually do in X?

Comment: Normally you don't configure the terminal to send different keys, you configure the program to behave differently to the key sequences it gets from the terminal. If I understand @Thomas Dickey's comment correctly, I think he's meaning its pretty trivial to reconfigure the programs response to the key characters, harder to get the terminal to send different keys

Comment: Did my question not demonstrate that the console is sending the same key codes for Left, Shift+Left, and Ctrl+Left?  If it did, then reconfiguring the console, not the text editor, is probably the correct solution.